# Liquibase generateChangeLog creates empty log file

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to run the generateChangeLog to get the current structure of the database schema. However,i see that liquibase always returns empty file.

```
$ liquibase --logLevel=debug --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --classpath="C:\temp\ojdbc8.jar" --changeLogFile="C:\db-changelog.xml" --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" --username=system --password=oracle  --defaultSchemaName=system generateChangeLog

Starting Liquibase at Tue, 23 Oct 2018 14:16:42 IST (version 3.6.2 built at 2018-07-03 11:28:09)
Liquibase command 'generateChangeLog' was executed successfully.
```

Also, though i have specified the loglevel as debug, i dont see liquibase generating logs .

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is there maybe a csv file named databasechangelog.csv generated in the folder?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, it was solved when I added the name of the scheme in the database URL:

```
?currentSchema=core
```

Command example:

```
$ liquibase --driver=org.postgresql.Driver \
     --classpath=postgresql-42.2.5.jar \
     --username=postgres \
     --password=postgres \
     --url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/data?currentSchema=core" \
     --changeLogFile=changelog-output.xml \
     generateChangeLog
```

Liquibase version: 3.7.0